# Writing plugin to affect the index.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to PHP and Wordpress plugin so I am a bit ignorant of some features. I want to write a plugin that restricts the number of posts shown on the main page (index.php). I want to use plugin because changing index.php of a certain theme would only affect that theme so I have been writing some code to actualize the concept but does not work and I want to know how I would achieve this to happen.

```
<?php
/*Initalize to 0 */
$numPosts = 0;

if(have_posts()) : 

    while($numPosts < 10) : the_post();
    $numPosts = $numPosts + 1; ?>

    <article class="post">
        <h2> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?> </a> </h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </article>
<?php endwhile;
else :
    echo '<p> No Contents Found </p>';
endif;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the theme will depend on what page is used to display the list of posts.
You can study and work out the used page by looking at the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Template_Hierarchy)

If you want to make small changes to affect a current theme please look at [child themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

As for you code, at first glance it looks somewhat correct.

Comment: Hi, I want above setting to be independent. That is, I want above setting to be consistent regardless of which theme I am applying

Comment: In wordpress backend Settings->Reading->Blog Pages Show at Most.

Then you can just define how many blog posts are show per page with out the needed to put it on the theme?

Comment: Yeah but I want to try it for myself! It is a practice!

Comment: Right... So you want it to be a plugin so it works regardless of what theme yet you don't want to use the settings that is configured for this? If you use a plugin for displaying custom content you maybe have to put placeholders or a widget into your theme anyway? Plugins are generally functionality changes and themes are generally visual changes. You amendment is a visual change so would be much easier completed as a theme/child theme...

Comment: How may I use a widget plugin to do that?

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to achieve something that isn't needed to be done? It has been completed the way WP have done so because this is how it is intended to be used...